# MethodNotAllowedHttpException using SoftDelete

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to soft delete my Document model which has an id of **106** for example. I already declared in my form as `DELETE` method also in my routes I define the `Route::delete` function also in my Document model already define the `use SoftDeletes;` but it's throwing me a **MethodNotAllowedHttpException** Any help why I got this error? Thanks for tips or help :)

routes:

```
Route::get('/documents/pending',
[
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\DocumentController@documentsSentForApproval',
    'as' => 'document.pending',
]);
Route::delete('/documents/pending/{id}/hide',
[
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\DocumentController@hideApprovalsDocument',
    'as' => 'document.softDeletePending',
]);
```

Controller:

```
public function hideApprovalsDocument(Document $id)
{

    $hide = Document::find($id);
    $hide->delete();

    return redirect()->back();

}
```

View:

```
@foreach ($pendingDocuments as $list)
   <tr class = "info">
   <td>

        <form class = "form-inline" role = "form" method = "DELETE" action = "/documents/pending/{{ $list->documentId }}/hide">

                <div class = "form-group">
                    <a href = "{{ route ('document.softDeletePending', $list->documentId) }}"><button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close"> Hide</button></a>
                </div>

            </form>

    </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Stacktrace:

```
in RouteCollection.php line 219
at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('DELETE')) in RouteCollection.php line 206
at RouteCollection->getRouteForMethods(object(Request), array('DELETE')) in RouteCollection.php line 158
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 823
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 691
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 675
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Debugbar.php line 51
at Debugbar->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(Debugbar), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a hidden `_method` input field declaring the Delete Request

There are no `PUT`, `PATCH` or `DELETE` for a form since forms can only process GET and POST requests

In order for Laravel to process a `DELETE` request you have to pass a

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
```

and Laravel will recognise your `DELETE` Request

You can read more about this in the [Docs, Spoofing Form Methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#resource-controllers)

Answer (score 1):

HTML forms do not support PUT, PATCH or DELETE actions. So, when defining PUT, PATCH or DELETE routes that are called from an HTML form, you will need to add a hidden _method field to the form. The value sent with the _method field will be used as the HTTP request method:

```
<form action="/foo/bar" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</form>
```

You may use the method_field helper to generate the _method input:

```
{{ method_field('DELETE') }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Already solve the problem by getting the `hidden input` in the View and using it in the Controller.

View:

```
<form class = "form-inline" role = "form" method = "POST" action = "/documents/pending/{{ $list->documentId }}/hide">

    {{ method_field('PATCH') }}

    <input type = "hidden" name = "softDelete" value = "{{ $list->documentId }}">

    <div class = "form-group">
        <a href = "{{ route ('document.softDeletePending', $list->documentId) }}"><button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close"> Hide</button></a>
    </div>

    <input type = "hidden" name = "_token" value = "{{ Session::token() }}">

</form>
```

Controller:

```
public function hideApprovalsDocument(Request $request, Document $id)
{
    //Getting the request in the View.
    $id = $request->get('softDelete');
    $hide = Document::where('id', '=', $id);
    $hide->delete();

    return redirect()->back();

}
```